# Is it possible to remove the border on Google CSE's results?

Tags: html, css, adsense, google-search, google-custom-search

I have installed a Google Custom Search through Adsense on a website.  The results that are returned show a gray (`#666666`) border around each one, with the following CSS:

```
.gsc-webResult.gsc-result, .gsc-results .gsc-imageResult {
      border-color: #666;
      background-color: white;
}
```

However, inside the AdSense search setup, I have set the border to `#FFFFFF` and other colors just to see if it will take affect.  It seems like no matter what color I enter for border, the same `#666666` is shown.  All of the other colors I specify get applied, but not the border.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** The search results are in an iframe, so I don't have access to the CSS.

Comment: Have you tried "border-color: #FFF !important;" ?

Comment: I should have specified in the original post, but the search results are in an iframe from Google.

Comment: You could always go in with javascript and change it. You should be able to edit content in an iframe.

Comment: That may be the route that I'll have to take.  I was just wondering if anyone else had experience with Google's CSE and could determine where the border was coming from.

Comment: Google allows you to do this.  I've done it and now I'm looking through my stuff so I can write an answer.  I have my own CSS just for my CSE search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some basic things like the border colors [are customized through your Google control panel](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/docs/ui.html#overview_howto).  Other things are customized with [your own CSS and JavaScript](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/docs/js/cselement-devguide.html#_themes).

http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/docs/ui.html

The following code is inserted in the `body` on the results page, where the results appear...

```
<div id="cse" style="width: 100%;">Loading</div>
<script src="//www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function parseQueryFromUrl () {
        var queryParamName = "q";
        var search = window.location.search.substr(1);
        var parts = search.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            var keyvaluepair = parts[i].split('=');
            if (decodeURIComponent(keyvaluepair[0]) == queryParamName) {
                return decodeURIComponent(keyvaluepair[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
            }
        }
     return '';
     }
     google.load('search', '1', {language : 'en'});
     google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
        var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl(' /* my google api key */ ');
        customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
        var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
        options.enableSearchResultsOnly(); 
        customSearchControl.draw('cse', options);
        var queryFromUrl = parseQueryFromUrl();
        if (queryFromUrl) {
                customSearchControl.execute(queryFromUrl);
        }
    }, true);
</script>
```

[Here is the link to the Google code wizard.](http://www.google.com/webelements/#!/custom-search)

[More about the JavaScript API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/docs/js/cselement-reference.html)

I'm sorry I could not find the exact links I used just six months ago.  The Google Developers documentation now seems to be a complete mess.  In the last few minutes, I found several 404 errors and links to pages declared as "deprecated".  Doesn't anyone at Google proof-read anything?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to put this all together.  It looks like I should be able to find what I need with the resources you provided me with.

Comment: You're welcome and good luck.  My CSE page is border-less so I know yours can be too.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to **find advanced settings** panel. See this one. It helped. 
http://tutes.in/2012/09/10/how-to-remove-bluegray-border-in-google-custom-search-engine-cse-results/

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.